# Unable to update and display the correct final scores after a player has won a Ping Pong match

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, counter

I have built a Ping Pong game using JavaScript and am trying to have the scores updated on the 'scoreboard' after each match.  Presently, the scores for both players on the scoreboard are on a some sort of a counter loop and will not stop.  I would like to have 1 win added for the winning player's stats to the scoreboard after each match.  How can I have the correct total number of wins reflected for each player on the scoreboard.  Your help would be much appreciated!

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nm4554L/)

```
<body>
  <h1>Ping Pong</h1>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <div id="sb">
    <h1>SCOREBOARD</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Player 1: <span id="player_1">0</span></li>
      <li> Player 2: <span id="player_2">0</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <script>
var count1_final = 0;
var count2_final = 0;

var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;
var ballY = 50;
var ballSpeedX = 10;
var ballSpeedY = 4;

var player1Score = 0;
var player2Score = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 2;

var showingWinScreen = false;

var paddle1Y = 250;
var paddle2Y = 250;
const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;

function calculateMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var root = document.documentElement;
  var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
  var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
  return {
    x:mouseX,
    y:mouseY
  };
}

function handleMouseClick(evt) {
  if(showingWinScreen) {
    player1Score = 0;
    player2Score = 0;
    showingWinScreen = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
      moveEverything();
      drawEverything();
    }, 1000/framesPerSecond);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseClick);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
    function(evt) {
      var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
      paddle1Y = mousePos.y - (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
    });
}

function ballReset() {
  var count1_final = 0;
  var count2_final = 0;
  if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
    player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {

    showingWinScreen = true;

  }

  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  ballX = canvas.width/2;
  ballY = canvas.height/2;
}

function computerMovement() {
  var paddle2YCenter = paddle2Y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
  if(paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35) {
    paddle2Y = paddle2Y + 6;
  } else if(paddle2YCenter > ballY + 35) {
    paddle2Y = paddle2Y - 6;
  }
}

function moveEverything() {
  if(showingWinScreen) {
    return;
  }

  computerMovement();

  ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
  ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

  if(ballX < 0) {
    if(ballY > paddle1Y &&
      ballY < paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

      var deltaY = ballY
          -(paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player2Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
      ballReset();
    }
  }
  if(ballX > canvas.width) {
    if(ballY > paddle2Y &&
      ballY < paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

      var deltaY = ballY
          -(paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player1Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
      ballReset();
    }
  }
  if(ballY < 0) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
  if(ballY > canvas.height) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
}

function drawNet() {
  for(var i=0;i<canvas.height;i+=40) {
    colorRect(canvas.width/2-1,i,2,20,'white');
  }
}


function drawEverything() {
  // next line blanks out the screen with black
  colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');

  if(showingWinScreen) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';

    if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 1 Won", 350, 200);
      // var count1 = 0;
      // var count1_final = count1 + 1;
      // player1final_score++;
      count1_final++;
      document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;
      console.log(count1_final)

    } else if(player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 2 Won", 350, 200);
      // var count2 = 0;
      // var count2_final = count2 + 1;
      // player2final_score++;
      count2_final++;
      // console.log(player2final_score)
      document.getElementById("player_2").innerHTML = count2_final;
      console.log(count2_final)

    }

    canvasContext.fillText("Play Again", 350, 500);
    return;
  }

  drawNet();

  // this is left player paddle
  colorRect(0,paddle1Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

  // this is right computer paddle
  colorRect(canvas.width-PADDLE_THICKNESS,paddle2Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

  // next line draws the ball
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');

  canvasContext.fillText(player1Score, 100, 100);
  canvasContext.fillText(player2Score, canvas.width-100, 100);
}

function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0,Math.PI*2,true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

function colorRect(leftX,topY, width,height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX,topY, width,height);
}
</script>
</head>
</body>

body {
  background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#gc {
  float: left;
}

#sb {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem.  I added a new function addFinalScore and call the function within the ballReset function.  Now the scoreboard is properly updating the score.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nm4554L/)

```
<body>
  <h1>Ping Pong</h1>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <div id="sb">
    <h1>SCOREBOARD</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Player 1: <span id="player_1">0</span></li>
      <li> Player 2: <span id="player_2">0</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <script>
var count1_final = 0;
var count2_final = 0;

var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;
var ballY = 50;
var ballSpeedX = 10;
var ballSpeedY = 4;

var player1Score = 0;
var player2Score = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 2;

var showingWinScreen = false;

var paddle1Y = 250;
var paddle2Y = 250;
const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;

function calculateMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var root = document.documentElement;
  var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
  var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
  return {
    x:mouseX,
    y:mouseY
  };
}

function handleMouseClick(evt) {
  if(showingWinScreen) {
    player1Score = 0;
    player2Score = 0;
    showingWinScreen = false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
      moveEverything();
      drawEverything();
    }, 1000/framesPerSecond);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseClick);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
    function(evt) {
      var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
      paddle1Y = mousePos.y - (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
    });
}

function ballReset() {
  if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
    player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {

    showingWinScreen = true;
    addFinalScore()
  }


  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  ballX = canvas.width/2;
  ballY = canvas.height/2;
}

function computerMovement() {
  var paddle2YCenter = paddle2Y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
  if(paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35) {
    paddle2Y = paddle2Y + 6;
  } else if(paddle2YCenter > ballY + 35) {
    paddle2Y = paddle2Y - 6;
  }
}

function moveEverything() {
  if(showingWinScreen) {
    return;
  }

  computerMovement();

  ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
  ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

  if(ballX < 0) {
    if(ballY > paddle1Y &&
      ballY < paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

      var deltaY = ballY
          -(paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player2Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
      ballReset();
    }
  }
  if(ballX > canvas.width) {
    if(ballY > paddle2Y &&
      ballY < paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

      var deltaY = ballY
          -(paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player1Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
      ballReset();
    }
  }
  if(ballY < 0) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
  if(ballY > canvas.height) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
}

function drawNet() {
  for(var i=0;i<canvas.height;i+=40) {
    colorRect(canvas.width/2-1,i,2,20,'white');
  }
}


function addFinalScore() {
  if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    count1_final++;
    document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;

  } else {
    count2_final++;
    document.getElementById("player_2").innerHTML = count2_final;
  }
}

function drawEverything() {
  // next line blanks out the screen with black
  colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');

  if(showingWinScreen) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';

    if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 1 Won", 350, 200);
      // count1_final++;
      // document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;
      console.log(count1_final)

    } else if(player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 2 Won", 350, 200);
      // count2_final++;
      // console.log(player2final_score)
      // document.getElementById("player_2").innerHTML = count2_final;
      console.log(count2_final)

    }

    canvasContext.fillText("Play Again", 350, 500);
    return;
  }

  drawNet();

  // this is left player paddle
  colorRect(0,paddle1Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

  // this is right computer paddle
  colorRect(canvas.width-PADDLE_THICKNESS,paddle2Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'white');

  // next line draws the ball
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');

  canvasContext.fillText(player1Score, 100, 100);
  canvasContext.fillText(player2Score, canvas.width-100, 100);
}

function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0,Math.PI*2,true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

function colorRect(leftX,topY, width,height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX,topY, width,height);
}
</script>
</head>
</body>

body {
  background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#gc {
  float: left;
}

#sb {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code:

```
if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 1 Won", 350, 200);
      var count1 = 0;
      var count1_final = count1 + 1;
      // player1final_score++;
      console.log(player1final_score)
      document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;

    } else if(player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 2 Won", 350, 200);
      var count2 = 0;
      var count2_final = count2 + 1;
      console.log(player2final_score)
      document.getElementById("player_2").innerHTML = count2_final;

    }
```

The offending text is here:

```
var count1 = 0;
var count1_final = count1 + 1;
```

You are saying to set the count back to zero, then you increment it by 1, hence why the scores don't go over 1.

As a solution, these variables representing the number of player wins should be defined globally, and then only increment them in the "win" function-- don't set them to zero before incrementing.

**EDIT:** You've now changed your code and your question has become a completely different one, but I will again show you the source of your error. It has to do with the logical flow of your program. You have:

```
var framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
      moveEverything();
      drawEverything();
    }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
```

which is being fired constantly throughout your program. However, even when a player wins, you are still calling `drawEverything()` constantly, and inside your `drawEverything()` function is your win counter:

```
function drawEverything() {
  // next line blanks out the screen with black
  colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');

  if(showingWinScreen) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';

    if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Player 1 Won", 350, 200);
      count1_final++; // <-- here
      document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;
      console.log(count1_final) <-- evidence here, count goes up constantly in the console

    }
... 
}
```

In other words, you need to rethink the flow of your program. How can you make it such that the player only "wins" once?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  You are right, I took out those variables you stated in your message above and added count1_final & count2_final as global variables set to '0' on the top of the page.  After making modifications to my code, my final scores after a player wins is on some sort of strange loop and the numbers will not stop going up.  If you have any other suggestions as to how to get the correct number of wins on the scoreboard I would really appreciate it.  I updated my fiddle above for reference.

Comment: Evidently you've replaced one bug for another. The best advice I can give you is to become acquainted with your browser's development tools (IE, Chrome, etc > hit F12), set breakpoints in your code (e.g. perhaps on where the score is incremented if you're having an issue with it incrementing too much), run through the behavior that causes the issue, and watch exactly what happens in your code. Try reading something like this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @MissyBur I have updated my answer in response to your new question. I did not see you had included a jsFiddle in your edit because it was embedded in your block of code. I have suggested an edit to your post as well.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines  will always set `count1` to zero, then set `count1_final` to `0 + 1 == 1` and the same is true a few lines below for count2_final.

```
if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    canvasContext.fillText("Player 1 Won", 350, 200);
    var count1 = 0;                    // <---------
    var count1_final = count1 + 1;     // <---------
    // player1final_score++;
    console.log(player1final_score)
    document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;
}
```

You need to *retrieve* `count1_final` and add one to *that*, which means you need to store count1_final and count2_final somewhere *outside* the `drawEverything` function. Declaring them in there with `var` makes them local to that function, and they are re-initialized to zero every time the function is called.

You could probably do that in `ballReset` -- when checking for a score `>= WINNING_SCORE` you can also check who won and add one to their win count: `count1_final++`

```
function ballReset() {
    if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
        player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE)
    {
        showingWinScreen = true;
        if (player1Score > player2Score) {
            count1_final++;
        }
        else {
            count2_final++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, The total score for the players on the scoreboard will still not go over 1.  Here is what I added: function ballReset() {
  if(player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
    player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    showingWinScreen = true;
     if (player1Score > player2Score) {
            count1_final++;
            document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = count1_final;
        }
        else {
            count2_final++;
            document.getElementById("player_2").innerHTML = count2_final;
        }
      }
  }

Comment: I noticed after answering that you have `player1Score `, `player1final_score`, `count1`, and `count1_final` and it's not clear to me what these four are meant to do (per player). In my head I think there only needs to be 2 vars per player: player's current score in current game, and number of games the player won. You _could_ have a third, player's total score added through all games, if you wanted to do statistics.  Without knowing what exactly these vars are for (e.g. doing a thorough analysis, probably running your program) I can't be more specific. The main point is don't zero the vars.

Comment: Yes.  I noticed that the player1final_score & player2final_score variables were not necessary and took them out. I have to keep the player1Score & player2Score bc that is the current score for the live game that is on the black canvas.  With my updated code, my game final game score on the scoreboard for the players after a win is on some sort of counter loop, the numbers won't stop going up. I would just like them to add on 1 to the score for each win.

Comment: I listed a fiddle link to the most current version of my game below. In addition,  I would love to have a third player be added to the game!  I'm not sure how to go about doing that, but if I could have more players and statistics on the scoreboard that would be awesome. https://jsfiddle.net/1nm4554L/  @Stephen P

Comment: Your tips have really helped me out, let me know if you have any more suggestions - thanks!

Comment: @Missy Glad to have helped ... you could show appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting my answer!

Comment: I would be happy to, but can you help me fix my issue?  My question still hasn't been answered.  Your help would be much appreciated!